# Trying to make a program with header files in C

Tags: c, header-files

I'm trying to make a program in C that uses header files and I'm getting an error. The program is supposed to add two numbers, add two numbers with a macro, and print a component in a typedef. There are three separate files:

functions.c

```
int add(int n1, int n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

functions.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

// function declaration
int add(int, int);

// macro declaration
#define ADD(n1, n2) n1 + n2

// typedef declaration
typedef struct {
    int age;
    char *name;
} person;

#endif
```

main.c (This is the main program that uses everything from functions.c and functions.h and prints the result.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", add(2, 6));
    printf("%d\n", ADD(3, 7));

    person engineer_man;
    engineer_man.age = 32;
    printf("engineer man's age is: %d\n", engineer_man.age);
}
```

I tried compiling by doing `gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wvla -Werror -fsanitize=address,undefined -o main main.c, but then it gave this error:`

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccbVAioe.o: in function `main':
/common/home/user/folder/main.c:5: undefined reference to `add'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: format your text do code properly, and post a [mcve]

Comment: You need to also compile and link `functions.c`. `gcc main.c functions.c -o main`

Comment: The macro needs to be `#define ADD(n1, n2) ((n1) + (n2))` so that it works correctly when called with arguments such a `ADD(a & b, c | d)` or other expressions involving operators with lower precedence than `+`, or when it is used in an expression involving operators with higher precedence than `+`: `x = ADD(a, b) * ADD(c, d)`.

Answer (score 2):

You never compile functions.c.

You need this:

```
gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wvla -Werror -fsanitize=address,undefined -o main main.c functions.c
                                                                 you forgot this ^
```

BTW, you also need to include "functions.h" in "functions.c":

```
#include "functions.h"

int add(int n1, int n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

Without including "functions.h" your program will build, but if for some reason the function declaration in `functions.h` doesn't match the function definiton in "functions.c", your program will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now!

Answer (score 2):

```
gcc -c functions.c
gcc -o main main.c functions.o
```

should also work well.  I omitted the compiler flags that need to be added in each case, depending on your need.